# JBPM demo error; JBoss server will not start

Tags: eclipse, ant, jboss

I am trying to run JBPM 6 on my Windows 7 computer.  I have downloaded the installer and run `ant install.demo`.  This all worked fine but the next step, running `ant start.demo` returns a "BUILD FAILED" followed by the message "JBoss application server did not start within 5 minutes".  The weird thing is that it worked the first time I ran it, but it froze my computer.  Now the server will not start.  Below I pasted the contents of `boot.log` found in ...\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log.  Does anyone know how I can get this started? Thank you.

```
10:23:30,647 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
10:23:31,337 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
10:23:31,406 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
10:23:31,408 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] Configured system properties:
    awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
    file.encoding = Cp1252
    file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
    file.separator = \
    java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
    java.class.path = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
    java.class.version = 52.0
    java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\endorsed
    java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
    java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre
    java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\mark\AppData\Local\Temp\
    java.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Progra~2\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG\pub;C:\jruby-1.7.10\bin;C:\tools;C:\Users\mark\Desktop\ansicon\x64;C:\Ruby200-x64\bin;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Users\mark\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Shoes\0.r1514\..;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Shoes\0.r1514\..;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin;.
    java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
    java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_05-b13
    java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
    java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.specification.version = 1.8
    java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
    java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
    java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
    java.version = 1.8.0_05
    java.vm.info = mixed mode
    java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
    java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
    java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
    java.vm.version = 25.5-b02
    javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
    javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
    javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
    javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
    javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
    jboss.bind.address = localhost
    jboss.home.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final
    jboss.host.name = thehost
    jboss.modules.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules
    jboss.node.name = thehost
    jboss.qualified.host.name = thehost
    jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone
    jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration
    jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data
    jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content
    jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log
    jboss.server.name = thehost
    jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\tmp
    line.separator = 

    logging.configuration = file:C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
    module.path = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules
    org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log
    org.kie.demo = true
    org.kie.example = false
    org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
    os.arch = amd64
    os.name = Windows 7
    os.version = 6.1
    path.separator = ;
    program.name = standalone.bat
    sun.arch.data.model = 64
    sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\classes
    sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre\bin
    sun.cpu.endian = little
    sun.cpu.isalist = amd64
    sun.desktop = windows
    sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
    sun.java.command = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules -jaxpmodule javax.xml.jaxp-provider org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final -b localhost --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Dorg.kie.demo=true -Dorg.kie.example=false
    sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
    sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
    sun.management.compiler = HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
    sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
    user.country = US
    user.dir = C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer
    user.home = C:\Users\mark
    user.language = en
    user.name = mark
    user.script = 
    user.timezone = America/New_York
    user.variant = 
10:23:31,448 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] VM Arguments: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms256m -Xmx512m -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\log\boot.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Users\mark\Downloads\jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone/configuration/logging.properties
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work with Java 8, you should use Java 7